# Improve SQL query performance. UNION vs OR in this situation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

**Problem**

So the situation that I am facing here with this SQL Query, is that it is taking about 12 seconds to run making the screen super slow.

**Goal**

Do the necessary changes in order to improve the performance and make it faster. I was thinking about instead of the `OR` in the Where clause to use the `UNION`?

```
SELECT Tool.*, Interview.*
    FROM Tool
INNER JOIN Interview ON Interview.Id = Tool.InterviewId
WHERE (Tool.ToolTypeId = @ToolTypeId 
AND Tool.Is_Active = 1
AND Tool.InterviewId = @InterviewId
AND Tool.ToolId = @ToolId
AND Tool.CustomerId = @CustomerId)

OR Tool.Id = (
    SELECT TOP 1 SubTool.Id
            FROM Tool SubTool
    INNER JOIN Interview subInterview ON subInterview.Id = SubTool.ToolId 
            WHERE SubTool.ToolTypeId = @ToolTypeId
            AND SubTool.Is_Active = 1  
            AND SubTool.InterviewId != @InterviewId  
            AND SubTool.ToolId = @ToolId
            AND subTool.CustomerId = @CustomerId
            AND convert(datetime, subTool.DateTime, 120) < @ToolDateTime
            ORDER BY subTool.DateTime DESC, subTool.StartDate DESC, 
                subTool.EndDate, subTool.Id DESC
)
                              
    ORDER BY Tool.StartDate, Tool.Id
```

***NOTE:*** I believe the actual query output is not necessary in this case, since we are looking for some structural issues that might be impacting the performance.

Comment: In order to assist with performance we need to see an execution plan using "Paste The Plan". Also you said union might improve it, well what happened when you tried it? Make sure its `union all` though, not `union`.

Comment: will try to have access to the database to be able to retrieve that, i will post it when i can. I just thought that it was possible to identify some issues with the query that could impact the performance, by the way using try_Convert instead of convert would improve the performance as well right?

Comment: SQL doesn't work like that, the syntax used to build the query doesn't represent the execution plan built by SQL Server. It uses a bunch of factors including indexes, statistics etc etc to determine how best to fulfil your request. Hence the only way to know what is happening is to inspect the execution plan. And while your idea of using a union is a common solution to this problem, again you'll only know if it helps when you try it.

Comment: `convert(datetime, Tool.DateTime, 120) < @ToolDateTime` looks inefficient, why is it the column not a `datetime` already? As does that subquery. For better help on performance, we need to see tables and indexes, and execution plans

Comment: it's something implemented in the beginning, now you can feel my pain, it doesn't make sense to have a column dateTime as a varchar, but well...now there's no chance to change it. I strongly disagree with this approach as well, i was told that it was due to datetime conversion to different timezones, but still doesn't make sense. Anyways i will try to have access to the execution plan to have a better sight of what SQL server is doing behind this

Comment: The usual case of providing example data and desired results IS relevant here. This is because optimisations to queries are often dependent on the exact functionality required, which a query on its own does not convey. You don't confirm if an Interview can relate to multiple tools. You don't confirm the data type of Tool.DateTime and/or why you need to use convert(). And so on and so forth. The very least you should do is provide the full DDL to confirm the constraints on the tables, but data to demonstrate the existing query's behaviour in ***all*** relevant corner cases would be better.

Comment: On the subject of datetime as strings. As style 120 is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss (24h)`, the string is already in such a format that it sorts in the same order as it would after conversion to a `DATETIME`. This means that you can convert the parameter `@ToolDateTime` to a string and use the `<` without converting the `DateTime` column, and get the same results. This would be SARGable and potentially reduce some of the cost. (Though I'm confident that this aspect of the execution plan is likely to be a minor contributor to the overall runtime.)

Comment: Both tables include an `id` column, so you ***can't*** use `SELECT Interview.*, Tool.*`

Comment: Can you add a _computed_ column to `Tool`? If so, you could use a `DateTime` column based on `[DateTime]` that is computed and indexed. What indexes exist on `Tool`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rephrasing the query to eliminate the subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

If you are looking for one row in the result set regardless of conditions, you can use:

```
SELECT TOP (1) Tool.*, Interview.*
FROM Tool JOIN
     Interview
     ON Interview.Id = Tool.InterviewId
WHERE Tool.ToolTypeId = @ToolTypeId AND
      Tool.Is_Active = 1
      Tool.ToolId = @ToolId AND
      Tool.CustomerId = @CustomerId AND
      (Tool.InterviewId = @InterviewId OR
       convert(datetime, Tool.DateTime, 120) < @ToolDateTime
      )
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Tool.InterviewId = @InterviewId THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         Tool.DateTime DESC, sTool.StartDate DESC, Tool.EndDate, Tool.Id DESC;
```

Your final `ORDER BY` suggests that you are expecting more than one row for the first condition.  So, you can use a subquery and window functions:

```
SELECT ti.*
FROM (SELECT Tool.*, Interview.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN Tool.InterviewId = @InterviewId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as cnt_interview_match,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY subTool.DateTime DESC, subTool.StartDate DESC, subTool.EndDate, subTool.Id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Tool JOIN
           Interview
           ON Interview.Id = Tool.InterviewId
      WHERE Tool.ToolTypeId = @ToolTypeId AND
            Tool.Is_Active = 1
            Tool.ToolId = @ToolId AND
            Tool.CustomerId = @CustomerId AND
            (Tool.InterviewId = @InterviewId OR
             convert(datetime, Tool.DateTime, 120) < @ToolDateTime
            )
      ) ti
WHERE InterviewId = @InterviewId OR
      (cnt_interview_match = 0 AND seqnum = 1);
```

Note that the subquery requires that the columns have different names, so you might need to fiddle with that.

Then, you want an index on `TOOL(ToolTypeId, Is_Active, ToolId, CustomerId, InterviewId, DateTime)`.  I assume that `Interview(Id)` is already indexed as the primary key of the table.

Comment: i will try your 2nd approach with Window functions since you are correct about expecting more than one row. One question, in the outside query you have WHERE Tool.InterviewId = @InterviewId OR (cnt_interview_match = 0 AND seqnum = 1); . Tool for instance  should be renamed to ti correct? shouldn't it be ti.interviewId and ti.cnt_interview_match ?  Anyways i will still try to have access to the execution plan so we will have a clear sight of what SQL Server is doing in the background

Comment: @JoãoEs . . . That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of what your query does (and by inference, what you want it to do) is different from @GordonLinoff's.

---

Gordon's queries could be paraphrased as...

- If there are rows with `Tool.InterviewId = @InterviewId`...

  - Return those rows and only those rows
- If there are no such rows to return...

  - Return the latest row for other `InterviewId`'s

---

My understanding of what your query actually ***does*** is that you want both possibilities returned together, at all times.

- This ambiguity is an example of why you ***really*** should include example data.

For example, this would be a re-wording or your existing query *(using `UNION` as per your own suggestion)*...

```
WITH
  filter_tool_customer AS
(
    SELECT Tool.*, Interview.*
      FROM Tool
INNER JOIN Interview ON Interview.Id = Tool.InterviewId
     WHERE Tool.ToolTypeId = @ToolTypeId 
       AND Tool.Is_Active  = 1
       AND Tool.ToolId     = @ToolId
       AND Tool.CustomerId = @CustomerId
),
  matched AS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM filter_tool_customer
   WHERE InterviewId = @InterviewId
),
  mismatched AS
(
  SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM filter_tool_customer
   WHERE InterviewId <> @InterviewId
     AND DateTime    <  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @ToolDateTime, 120)
ORDER BY DateTime DESC,
         StartDate DESC,
         EndDate,
         Id DESC
),
  combined AS
(
  SELECT * FROM matched
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM mismatched
)
SELECT * FROM combined ORDER BY StartDate, Id
```